# Git basics, How can I grab files from git?

Tags: git, ssh

I am new to git so chances are there is a simple answer.

I have a git command for grabbing a site

```
git clone git@devel.foobar.com:foob.com.git
```

Now when I run this I am prompted for a password via GUI.(Enter a password to unlock the private key) My local root, and user passwords don't work.

what's going on? Do I need to get a password from the git repository manager?

EDIT- Sorry, It was for grabbing drupal sites. I thought this may have been a common issue among others here.

Comment: Can you post the answer as an answer instead of an edit please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You answered it yourself in the question.

The password is the password/passprase you make locally when you create an ssh key. So if you set your password for the ssh key to `foobar` , then the password that you would need to enter when it asks you would be `foobar` - your password probably (and should be!) different, that's just an example.

If you forgot your password, then you should create a new one. For instructions on how to do that, take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys).

Comment: Thanks, yeah for some reason I couldn't hit the answer button myself so I just put it in the question. Password, Passphrase threw me off because it wasn't consistent and a gui window popped up while working from the terminal.

Comment: @winchendonsprings You're welcome. And that's confusing for me as well at times. Mainly at like 4AM. :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is - password is the passphrase you make locally when you create an ssh key.